# Firefox will not exit properly

Tags: linux, firefox, debian

I'm running Firefox 27.0.1 on debian 7.2 and if I close firefox, wait, then start it up again it complains that it's already running somewhere.

I have to first killall firefox before running it again

```
killall firefox
firefox
```

I can leave it over night and the same problem happens, firefox is not closing down properly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have seen this this issue occasionally with 27.x on both Linux and Windows.  It seems to be intermittently failing to close.  I suspect answer might be to wait for Mozilla to release a less buggy browser.  I haven't spent time trying to find the root cause since it is infrequent for me.

Comment: Found it, it was the .parentlock file in my profile